# Suggetion for finding $ \lim _{n\to \infty} n^d \sum^n_{i=1} \frac{1}{(i+n)^{d+1}}$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, analysis

\begin{equation}
\displaystyle \lim _{n\to \infty} n^d\displaystyle \sum^n_{i=1} \frac{1}{(i+n)^{d+1}}
\end{equation}

$ n$ and $d$ are natural numbers

I don't know how to approach this problem. My idea is to use squeeze theorem, so it will be$\displaystyle \lim _{n\to \infty}A \leq \displaystyle \lim _{n\to \infty} n^d\displaystyle \sum^n_{i=1} \frac{1}{(i+n)^{d+1}}\leq\displaystyle \lim _{n\to \infty} B$. However, even though I think I find the "A", I can't find a suitable "B"

For A: my idea is that since $\displaystyle \sum^n_{i=1} \frac{1}{(i+n)^{d+1}}=\frac{1}{(1+n)^{d+1}}+...+\frac{1}{(n+n)^{d+1}}$.

Then it will be greater than $\dfrac{1}{(n+n)^{d+1}}+...+\dfrac{1}{(n+n)^{d+1}}$  for n times which is $\dfrac{n}{(2n)^{d+1}}$

Thus $\dfrac{n^d\cdot n}{(2n)^{d+1}}\leq\displaystyle  n^d\displaystyle \sum^n_{i=1} \frac{1}{(i+n)^{d+1}}\implies \dfrac{1}{2^{d+1}}\leq\displaystyle  n^d\displaystyle \sum^n_{i=1} \frac{1}{(i+n)^{d+1}}$

But after this, I can't find "B". My first idea is that $\dfrac{1}{(i+n)^{d+1}}\leq\dfrac{1}{n^{d+1}}$, but it will only give me $n^d\displaystyle \sum^n_{i=1} \frac{1}{(i+n)^{d+1}}\leq 1$.

Also, I tried some other method, but all of them will only give me "over" large result for B.

Hence, any suggestions for approaching this question? Thanks!

Comment: $$...=\lim_{n\to \infty }\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n\frac{1}{(1+\frac{i}{n})^{d+1}}=...$$ which is a Riemann sum...

Comment: In fact, I reach there, and I kind of feel that is a Riemann sum, but I don't know how to deal with it, since for normal Reimann sum it looks like $\displaystyle \sum f(\xi_i)\Delta x_i$   and "$ i $" is just an index. However, in  this formula, I think the function is $\dfrac{1}{(1+\frac{i}{n})^{d+1}} $, $i$ becomes something in the function, and the number of partition $n$ is also involved

Comment: The limit (for $d\geqslant1$) is the $d$th coefficient of the series expansion of $$f(x)=\log\left(\frac{x}{2}-1\right)-\log(x-1).$$ Indeed, $f(x)=\frac{x}{2}+\frac{3
   x^2}{8}+\frac{7
   x^3}{24}+\frac{15
   x^4}{64}+\frac{31
   x^5}{160}+O\left(x^6\right).$